# How is correctly way to do callback of Twitter acount in my TYPO3 extension

Tags: twitter, typo3, twitter-oauth, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

We are developing an TYPO3 extension that is in charge of managing the social network profiles. We used the extension "ps_social" as a guide for understand the social media network APIs could work with TYPO3 through Adapter Pattern.

I have the proof of concept of the implementation to authenticate a profile and publish in it but through only in PHP, now we want to take it to the TYPO3 extension.

My question is about the callback when authenticating a profile. Our extension sends us to the social network and when we return to our web page, with the token in the url, this does not change and shows the same screen of the plugin before redirect to the authentication in the social network. The callback url in manage app in Twitter has the id of our plugin's page. I check url for change the plugin action but doesn't work.

We see that this step is fundamental to be able to later make publications to the authenticated profiles in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved creating a new plugin. In the configuration of application in Twitter I can not set parameters as controller and actions, for example; only the page id. I had to create a plugin in my TYPO3 extension that execute in one page the action for get information of callback, process and return the page with the list of social profiles. This We did it in each one social networks (Facebook, Google+ and Instagram) for their callback URL to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that your authentication service is not triggered when returning to the TYPO3 site. Whether or not your service will trigger depends on several configuration options. By default, your service will only trigger when a POST login action is taking place - but there are options to define that, for example, the authentication service must always attempt to fetch (and thus authenticate) the user even if there is no POST login data (instead, GET parameters may be used to determine if authentication should be attempted).

There is also a caveat if you intend to log in BE users using this method. I've noticed that if you attempt to log in a BE user in the FE, then no action or configuration will be respected *unless* an existing BE user cookie exists (which it will if you've ever been logged into the BE). If you use the authentication service to log in to the BE normally there isn't this problem - it only applies if you try to do it in FE.

TL;DR: I'm guessing you need to configure the "always auth user" setting for the targeted BE/FE context, using parameters described in the "advanced" section of this link: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/Typo3ServicesReference/Authentication/Index.html